# What is the default interpreter used to run the script without shebang?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script

Having super simple shell script like so:

```
echo "Hello World"
```

with no shebang line, the executable bit set on the file and called like so:

```
./my_sript
```

what is the interpreter used to run the script? How is it found by the system and where is the default interpreter defined?.

Answer (score 3):

The *default* shell for this user (not the current shell) will be used. Have a look at `/etc/passwd` - it's defined there, and will be launched at login. You can use `chsh` to change the current user's default shell.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree with the jvb answer.  Consider the following csh formatted script, without a shebang:

```
#
set x = 'a'
if ($x == 'a') then
   echo "running csh"
endif
```

On my machine, where my default shell is (t)csh, the result is:

```
anukis% ./shell-test
running csh
```

Now, edit the script to delete the top line:

```
set x = 'a'
if ($x == 'a') then
   echo "running csh"
endif
```

Now re-run it and the result is:

```
anukis% ./shell-test
./shell-test: 6: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
```

What's the difference?  The ancient way to differenciate csh from (Bourne) sh: if the first line starts with an octothorpe ("#"), assume it's a C-shell script, otherwise a Bourne(-type) shell.